# PHP form $_POST passes data but the variables are empty once in a while

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, form-submit

I have a form based on this simple code. It works just fine in 999/1000 cases, but yesterday I got blank row in database and blank variables in email. It never happened before. I found out, that client who filled the form was filling it on mobile, android, it was filled properly, but then blank variables came to me. Really dont know, where the problem is, because every time I test it, it works. Any ideas?

```
<?php

include 'dbconn.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$resultSet = $con->query("INSERT INTO `contact` (`username`,`email`) 
VALUES ('$username','$email')");

$message='Variable username:'.$username.', variable email: '.$email;   
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->msgHTML($message);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->send();

}

?>
```

The form is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required> 
Email: <input type="email" name="email" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Add a check for empty before adding to the db

Comment: I was waiting for some one else to point out the security hole. This is open to SQL injection attacks. Also you say you know it was filled in properly -- how do you know?

Comment: the client who filled in the form and blank row came reached us, so I know the form was filled in properly via mobile

Comment: I simply would not take a users word for it. Especially if this is a one-of

Comment: best way; check to see if any inputs are not empty; using `isset()` is not the best. Edit: Ah, seeing @nogad 's comment here also, I didn't see it. To add, use a ternary operator and use a default value if empty; it's another option or just let them know that they cannot leave it empty.

Comment: you should also ALTER your table so that the affected rows don't allow for NULL/EMPTY values. Question is starting to be too broad at this point.

Comment: What do you suggest instead of isset if you say its not the best way? Thank you all guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers will respect the `required` attribute, so you should validate your $_POST values on the server side.

Something like:

```
<?php

include 'dbconn.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

if(isset($username) && isset($email)){
    $resultSet = $con->query("INSERT INTO `contact` (`username`,`email`) VALUES ('$username','$email')");

    $message='Variable username:'.$username.', variable email: '.$email;   
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->msgHTML($message);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->send();

    }
} else {
    // echo fail response
}
?>
```

Comment: yes, thank you, but I know that the case of blank row was made by proper filling in. The problem is not that someone sends blank form. The problem is, that the form was filled in, but the data has been lost.

Comment: perhaps they clicked the submit button twice..?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you relying on client side validation which can easily be bypassed.

I recommending checking that the username and email keys in the $_POST array have values before inserting them into the database and sending the email.

For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // Insert and send email
}
```

Comment: yes, i am aware of this, but the blank row situation happened, when client actually filled in the form. The form was filled in properly, it was sent to php, but then it came empty. Is it possible to lose the data in time of processing the script?

Comment: I can't really answer that. Could be human error or something else. The thing I would take away from this is checking data on the server before processing it will prevent a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for if they are null or not if null then not to process it

```
<?php
include 'dbconn.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    if(!is_null(trim($email))&& !is_null(trim($username))){
        $resultSet = $con->query("INSERT INTO `contact` (`username`,`email`) VALUES ('$username','$email')");
        $message='Variable username:'.$username.', variable email: '.$email;   
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
        $mail->msgHTML($message);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->send();
    }
}
?>
```